# How to resolve Veracode issue "cweid201 Information Exposure Through Sent Data"?

Tags: .net, veracode

Veracode reported following issue with my code:

> cweid201
>
> Information Leakage:Information Exposure Through Sent Data

Issue to be resolved at below 2 instances

1) The error is given for the line

```
memoryStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
```

Code snippet is:

```
byte[] byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(compressedString);
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray)) {
  memoryStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
  memoryStream.Position = 0;
   using (GZipInputStream gzipInputStream = new GZipInputStream(memoryStream)) {
      using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(gzipInputStream)) {
        return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
      }
   }
 }
```

2) The error is given for the line

```
     textWriter.WriteLine(readLine);
```

Code snippet is :

```
     textWriter = new StreamWriter(path);
     string readLine;
while ((readLine = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null) {
            textWriter.WriteLine(readLine);
}
```

Can anyone explain how I can resolve the issue in above instances?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation for that issue: http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/201.html ?

Comment: yes , I have checked the documentation.. but not sure how to resolve the issue with my code